# Disable wireless power save

Tags: wifi, power-management

Is there a way I can disable the power saving functionality of the wireless in OS-X Sierra (10.12.6)?

The issue I'm trying to address is where the wireless goes to sleep and wakes up every few hundred millisecond to check for incoming data. This is extremely annoying as I have latency sensitive applications which send data to my laptop.

I've been able to work around the issue by doing:

```
ping -i 0.2 192.168.0.1 # <- my router
```

This keeps the wireless card from going idle and into power save mode.

Also note that I am not even on battery. I'm plugged in to power.

This is the result of me pinging my laptop from another machine on the network:

```
64 bytes from 192.168.0.147: icmp_seq=383 ttl=62 time=102 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.147: icmp_seq=384 ttl=62 time=38.1 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.147: icmp_seq=385 ttl=62 time=47.8 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.147: icmp_seq=386 ttl=62 time=80.5 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.147: icmp_seq=387 ttl=62 time=96.0 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.147: icmp_seq=388 ttl=62 time=120 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.147: icmp_seq=389 ttl=62 time=37.3 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.147: icmp_seq=390 ttl=62 time=67.7 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.147: icmp_seq=391 ttl=62 time=93.4 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.147: icmp_seq=392 ttl=62 time=115 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.147: icmp_seq=393 ttl=62 time=140 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.147: icmp_seq=394 ttl=62 time=37.0 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.147: icmp_seq=395 ttl=62 time=100 ms
```

This is the result of the same ping from another machine but with doing `ping -i 0.2 192.168.0.1` from the laptop:

```
64 bytes from 192.168.0.147: icmp_seq=396 ttl=62 time=42.3 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.147: icmp_seq=397 ttl=62 time=37.3 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.147: icmp_seq=398 ttl=62 time=38.0 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.147: icmp_seq=399 ttl=62 time=37.2 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.147: icmp_seq=400 ttl=62 time=37.5 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.147: icmp_seq=401 ttl=62 time=37.5 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.147: icmp_seq=402 ttl=62 time=37.0 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.147: icmp_seq=403 ttl=62 time=37.6 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.147: icmp_seq=404 ttl=62 time=36.9 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.147: icmp_seq=405 ttl=62 time=37.2 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.147: icmp_seq=406 ttl=62 time=39.1 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.147: icmp_seq=407 ttl=62 time=43.0 ms
```

Notice how low, and stable it is now?

I've been able to address this issue in other operating systems by disabling the wireless card's/driver's power save functionality. I just don't know how to do it in OS-X.

The Laptop is a 2017 MacBook Pro 13-inch
Network card is AirPort Extreme. Firmware Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0

Comment: Which card do you specifically have? This is definitely a driver function and so it'll be a bit of a weird solution depending on your card.

Comment: Added hardware specs to bottom of question.

Comment: How about using a USB-C to Ethernet adapter for wired access?

Comment: I frequently unplug my laptop and go somewhere with it for a bit (e.g. a meeting). Wired connections are extremely annoying as any existing connections get killed.